# Deconstruct url path with user input in react native

Tags: react-native

I'm looking to make a fetch request to an API, in my code I added a text input:

```
   constructor(props) {

    super(props)
    this.state = {
      UserInput: '',
    }
  }

<TextInput onChangeText={(UserInput) => 
this.setState({UserInput})} value={this.state.UserInput} />
```

I can definitely see `UserInput` variable if I render `<Text>{this.state.UserInput}</Text>` in my view, however I'm trying to use that variable to generate a dynamic url path for my api request.

The url looks like that `https://api.trading.com/1.0/stock/msft/company` msft is  what I have to change by `UserInput`

In pure javascript, I usually do something like this:

```
  const userstock = UserInput;
  const path = "https://api.trading.com/1.0/stock/";
  const end = "/company";
  const url = path + userstock + end;
```

I changed var by const because it's react native but it's still not working,

> Can't find variable: UserInput

I also tried `https://api.trading.com/1.0/stock/${UserInput}/company` can someone help on this please? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you write,it works if you render `<Text>{this.state.UserInput}</Text>`!
Why not write like this:

```
const userstock = this.state.UserInput;
```

or :

```
"https://api.trading.com/1.0/stock/"+ this.state.UserInput +"/company"
```

I suggest you should read official document and learn more about `props and state`!

Comment: thanks it says undefined is not an object with both solutions, here's my entire code https://pastebin.com/SXHny7Qw

Comment: It has no `auto-binding` in ES6，so `onPress={this.GetValue}>` should be `onPress={this.GetValue.bind(this)}>`,you can try this!

Comment: I used let userstock = this.state.UserInput; it worked fine!! Thanks so much for taking the time. Appreciate it